# How to pass a dynamic variable to a 'component' and then display it - VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I can not display a variable (which is the link of an image) in my `component` I am lost ...

(To help you, I'm in a table and click on the icon that opens a pdf)

Thanks you !

```js
Vue.component('modal', {
    template: '#modal-template-pdf',
    props: {
        lien: String
    }
});

let appCompta = new Vue({
        data: {
            showModalActive: false,
            currentModalPdfLink: '',
        }
}).$mount('#'+id+' #app-compta')
```

```html
<img slot="apercu" slot-scope="props" class="iconeged main" src="images/ico_pdf.png"
             v-bind:currentModalPdfLink='props.row.imglien'
             @click="showModalActive = true"
        >

<modal v-if="showModalActive" @close="showModalActive = false" v-bind:lien="currentModalPdfLink">
        <h3 slot="header">Aperçu PDF</h3>
    </modal>

    <script type="text/x-template" id="modal-template-pdf">
        <transition name="modal">
            <div class="modal-mask">
                <div class="modal-wrapper">
                    <div class="modal-container">

                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <slot name="header">
                                default header
                            </slot>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <slot name="body">
                                {{currentModalPdfLink}}
                                <iframe height='100%' width='100%' frameborder='0' :src="currentModalPdfLink"/>
                            </slot>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <slot name="footer">
                                <button class="modal-default-button" @click="$emit('close')">
                                    FERMER
                                </button>
                            </slot>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </transition>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `currentModalPdfLink` is your pdf-link?
The name of the prop that you are passing is `src` so you need to refer to it in your component with the same name:

```
Vue.component('modal', {
    template: '#modal-template-pdf',
    props: ['src']
});
```

Comment: **I have the following error** : "Property or method "currentModalPdfLink" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property."

**I replaced what you told me in the component and The first line of modal with : ` v-bind:src="currentModalPdfLink"`**

Comment: Problem is, I cannot see your Vue-App-structure. To which element are you binding your vue-instance? Do you use Vue-devtools (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd)? It will help you see all your vue-data and props.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer and sorry for my delay. I do not use Node but php and axios for the data I give to VueJS. (So I do not have the extension either). I do not really know what to give you more ... I'm trying to use "props" to pass a variable but I only find cases with several variables or tables.